# converting hexadecimal data to readable string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, hex, converters

I have few lines of hexadecimal data which I need to convert  to strings I would be able to read using Python 3

example for the way each line looks:

`00000000: BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B    =..Csf,@I_.C0.<;`

I tried two options I found in other posts and they did not work:

`bytearray.fromhex("00000000: BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B    =..Csf,@I_.C0.<;").decode()`

returned on the terminal:

> bytearray.fromhex("00000000: BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B    =..Csf,@I_.C0.<;").decode()
> ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 8

and the other one:

`bytes.fromhex('00000000: BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B    =..Csf,@I_.C0.<;').decode('utf-8')`

returned on terminal:

> bytes.fromhex('00000000: BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B    =..Csf,@I_.C0.<;').decode('utf-8')
> ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 8

I see both returned basically the same thing so I am guessing I do something wrong but can't figure out what it is.

do I need to import a library I don't know about?

Comment: this is the hex string `BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B`

Comment: if i run it only on that part it returns this:   
 bytearray.fromhex("BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B").decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: `bytes.fromhex("BD 99 91 43 73 E6 AC C0 C9 5F 93 43 B0 9D 3C 3B").decode('utf-16')`?

Comment: ok it looks like it does work but it gives me chinese/japanese in the terminal , is it fixable or i need to learn chinese?

Comment: Where and how are you getting this data? this chinese seems gibberish to me

Comment: its out of a game resS file that i want to read for a project im working on.
the thing is the company is from the US so i doubt they wrote it in Chinese or Japanese